# How to revert git repo while preserving the commit history?

Tags: git

Here's what I have:

```
dbd7868 (HEAD -> master) commit 3
19ea7e8 commit 2
5b4baae commit 1
```

I want all files to be in the exact same state as they were in `commit 2`. Here's what I tried:

```
git checkout 19ea7e8
git commit -m "reverted to commit 2"
```

But this was the result:

```
HEAD detached at 19ea7e8
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Desired result:

```
xxxxxxx (HEAD -> master) reverted to commit 2
dbd7868 commit 3
19ea7e8 commit 2
5b4baae commit 1
```

---

I tried looking around but I found answers where a command would've left `commit 3` out of the history and then I found answer where it was not clear if the history was preserved or not.

---

**Edit:** I had to set the test project again after trying one of the suggested solutions. Here's what I have now:

```
9c4180f (HEAD -> master) jkl
38029d0 ghi
830efcd def
ae96f00 abc
```

Here's what I want:

```
xxxxxxx (HEAD -> master) def again
9c4180f jkl
38029d0 ghi
830efcd def
ae96f00 abc
```

Commit `def again` should be exactly the same as `def`. To clarify, I want to be able to go to any commit.

Comment: You could try `git reset 19ea7e8` and then `git commit -am "reverted to commit 2"`. I think that might do what you want.

Comment: That erases the history. Now I have commit 1 -> commit 2 -> revert commit 2.

Comment: What about `git checkout . 19ea7e8`?

Comment: Doesn't work: `error: pathspec '19ea7e8' did not match any file(s) known to git.`

Comment: Might have put the . and commit the wrong way around.

Comment: Git reset doesn't erase history. If you make a branch at `9c4180f` you won't lose it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution thanks to John Ilacqua.

Here are the exact commands I entered:

```
git checkout 830efcd .
git commit -am "revert def"
```

And here's the output:

```
684b0bb (HEAD -> master) revert def
9c4180f jkl
38029d0 ghi
830efcd def
ae96f00 abc
```

Comment: That's *mostly* the right answer (you also need to *remove* any files that were added since the commit you are extracting). If you call this "revert" in your commit message, though, you will mislead Git users who have gotten used to the idea that in Git, *revert* means *undo* aka *back out*.  It does not mean *go back to* aka *revert to*. This is an unfortunate case of English-language ambiguity (revert can mean either "undo" or "go back to").

Comment: @user3670011 Why did you unaccept my answer? Did it not answer your question?

Answer (score 7):

You can use the command `git revert <hash1> <hash2> ..`

Try the following command:

```
git revert dbd7868
```

It will create a new commit which will be a revert of commit 3.

If you want to revert any other commit, just run the revert command with the commits hash. Eg:

```
git revert 5b4baae #to revert commit 1
git revert 19ea7e8 #to revert commit 2
```

In all cases, the revert commit will come on top of commit 3.

Comment: What if I want to go any point in time, not just the previous commit?

Comment: I updated the new commit structure on my question. I ran the command `git revert 830efcd #to revert def` and the output was `fatal: bad revision '#to'`

Comment: `#to revert commit 1` was a comment for you to understand. Run only `git revert 5b4baae`